# Git слияние репозиториев

Tags: git

Скачал репозиторий с gitlab, внес кучу изменений и оказывается он без локального гита, как мне внести изменения в удаленный репозиторий? Он за неделю не менялся.

Comment: Сделать git clone как обычно и просто переместить изменённые файлы на место склонированного репозитория?

Comment: @andreymal много чего было изменено, не вариант(

Comment: А что мешает это «много чего» взять и переместить?

Comment: Ну или наоборот, сделать git clone как обычно и переместить папочку `.git` в папочку с изменениями, суть будет та же

Comment: @andreymal то что не было локального гита и не понятно что изменил что нет

Comment: Перемещайте сразу всё, не стесняйтесь

Comment: @andreymal вот за этот вариант спасибо!

Comment: Однако оба варианта погалаются на то, что содержимое этого вашего скачанного «без локального гита» действительно соответствует содержимому полноценного git-репозитория, поэтому обязательно проверьте через `git status` и `git diff` что никакие нужные файлы не пропали например